# AWS EC2 Instance Status Check says “Instance reachability check failed”

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have been running my moodle server in aws ec2 t2-medium instance. From yesterday onward the moodle website associated woth my server is not loading and I am not able to SSH to this instance. I have tried Stop/Start and rebooting the instance, but the problem persists. The status check for the instance says: 'Instance reachability check failed'. Losing the data and starting from scratch is not an option here for me, also the t2-medium instance has been rented for 3 years, so losing this instance is also big issue. Upon checking the security group, inbound traffic for ssh on port 22 is for all ips. On checking the "Get system log" from 'Monitor and troubleshoot, no error can be seen and the login prompt is coming. The screenshot also shows the login prompt. Any help is much appreciated.

**More Informations**

- Server is running ubuntu 18.04
- See some of the metrics monitoring attached here.
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you need to do is stop the instance and snapshot the EBS volume(s) attached.  At the very least, even if you can't recover the instance directly, you will be able to restore and remount those files to a new instance.  I would also create an AMI from it, which will allow you to launch it directly later.

I am surprised stopping/starting the instance didn't resolve the issue.  I might also temporarily change the instance type after stopping (like to a t2 large or something) to further attempt to get AWS to assign your instance to another physical machine.  You can always switch it back if that works.

If all that fails, you can launch a new instance either from the AMI you created, or a new instance and then mount the old EBS volumes to it to extract any old data you needed (assuming you don't release the EBS volumes when you terminate the instance).